# fabric js - How to check if the pattern applied to the svg

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I have an svg in which I apply an image pattern. Sometimes the pattern is not applying and when I re-render again it gets applied. so is there a way to check if the pattern is applied successfully or not?

```
function gdrawGenSvgobj(varsvg, varpattern, callback) {
            if (varsvg == 0 || varsvg == undefined) { callback(); }
            else {
                fabric.loadSVGFromURL(varsvg, function (objsvg) {
                    var gensvg = new fabric.PathGroup(objsvg, { left: 0, top: 0, width: 620, height: 641 });
                    gensvg = gensvg.setPatternFill({ source: varpattern, repeat: 'repeat', offsetX: 'left', offsetY: 'top' });
                    canva.add(gensvg);
                    callback();
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[setPatternFill](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setPatternFill) is having callback as second argument, call `requestrenderAll/renderAll` there.

As given in demo.

```
object.setPatternFill({
  source: 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/escheresque_ste.png',
  repeat: 'repeat'
},canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Comment: thanks but, that's not what I'm looking for. I have tried that already. it still not applying sometimes. I'm looking for a way to check if it is applied successfully or not.

Comment: @SO-user, can you make snippet/fiddle producing the issue?